# Chrome remote connection connects but then drops out

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am really struggling to get **Google Chrome Remote Debugging** to work! I have the phone setup and confirmed:

[image]

Then below are what I see in `chrome://inspect/#devices` and also `F12` (both open at the same time);

[image]

It flashes with the "Connected" for about 3 seconds, and then goes to:

> Offline
>
> ## ZX1G324RSV Pending authentication: please accept debugging session on the device.

It's driving me nuts, as it *should* be simple to do, but it just doesn't want to play ball :/ Do I need to do anything special? I've used it before on this PC and although I had some fun and games with it the first time around, it worked after that.

There seems to be a ton of posts/articles about how to fix it, but none of them are working for me. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=450492 for example.

Comment: Mmmm well I seem to have got it working. For some reason it works fine on another USB port. Not quite sure why! At least this will get me through this issue, but it would still be nice to find out why its not working on the other port

Comment: USB port problems?

Comment: Same as @AndrewNewby, changed USB port and the connection remained, doesn't drop. This is not my own PC, but work's so I don't know the diff in ports, maybe USB 2/3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download Android SDK here ("SDK Tools Only" section) and unzip the content.
2. Run SDK Manager.exe and install Android SDK platform tools
3. Open up the Command prompt (simply by pressing the windows button and type in cmd.exe)
4. Enter the path with ex: cd c:/downloads/sdk/platform-tools
5. Open ADB by typing in adb.exe
6. Run the following command by typing it and pressing enter: adb devices
7. Check if you get the prompt on your device, if you still can't see your phone in Inspect Devices run the following commands one by one (excluding the ") "adb kill-server" "adb start-server" "adb devices"

Comment: The question is why does the connection drop.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the things that you can try:

1. Try different USB cable(s)
2. Try different USB ports on your machine(for some people using 2.0 port worked out)
3. Try the same process, with unchecked 'Discover USB Devices' in chrome://inspect (then Chrome will connect through the ADB server, not directly) ==> This solution worked in my scenario.